# Origin of "Hotel"

Tags: meaning, etymology

As in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motel) "a **motel** is a hotel designed for motorists and usually has a parking area for motor vehicles."

So, I thought that since "M" refers to motorists, perhaps "H" in hotel refers to horsists? In this regard, hotel was probably coined as a term for a place for travelers and their horses. Am I right? If not, what's origin of hotel?

Comment: ***Motel (n.)***
1925, coined from motor- + hotel. Originally a hotel for automobile travellers. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Motel+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hotel comes from the French language; nothing to do with horses.**

---

According to [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php):

> [hotel (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hotel)
>
> 1640s, "public official residence; large private residence," **from French hôtel** "a mansion, palace, large house," from Old French ostel, hostel "a lodging" (see hostel). Modern sense of "an inn of the better sort" is first recorded 1765. The same word as [hospital](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hospital&allowed_in_frame=0).

(emphasis: **bold**)

---

Wikipedia essentially says the same thing as above, however they provide no source for their [etymology section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel#Etymology).

---

Using Google with Etymology + Hotel will provide the following graphic:

[image: hotel]

Comment: The presence of a circumflex accent in French, usually indicates that a letter *S* has been elided - as in *fenêtre*, meaning *window* - from the Latin *fenestra*. This immediately indicates that *hotel* is from *hostel*.